# How to disable updating of structure.sql in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

Is there a config option that would let us disable updating of the structure.sql?

It constantly updates everytime we run a migration and we don't need it to update.

We just need it for legacy tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable that in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

See the configuration guide [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record).

Comment: Cool. Thats the best. You wouldn't happen to know of a way for rails 3? :)

Comment: Ohh, I see. We had to monkey-patch that, unfortunately.